# Unable to make my bios see my sata hdd

Tags: hard-drive, sata, pata

I know there are many question about that, but I tried everything and I'm still not able to make my bios see my sata2 hdd.
I've got a QDI motherbord with no sata port; only 2 ide ports.

I had an old ide hdd, now i've removed it and bought a sata2 hdd. Since my pc has no sata slots i bouth a ide-to-sata adapter.

So, i don't have any os installed on the new drive, and the old drive is removed.
My problem is that I'm unable to see my hdd on bios. I suppose that my bios, since it's an old version, doesn't have sata drivers, but I don't know if I must install it and also I dont know how to do it.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Check here to see if there is a BIOS update for your motherboard:

http://www.qdigrp.com/qdisite/eng/support/driver.htm

BIOS upgrades will often include new features and if you're lucky this will address your issue.

Having said that, I think that using an adapter may be introducing a problem (would the BIOS "see" a SATA drive attached to an IDE port?)

A second option would be to try a PCI or PCI-X SATA add-non card. Since these cards connect directly to the PCI bus, your BIOS *might* be able to see the drive in this manner. They are relatively inexpensive. (http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/category/category_slc.asp?CatId=1455&srkey=sata%20card)

Comment: +1 for add-on cards.  much better than adapters for this purpose.

Comment: My instant thought, after reading the question, is that the adapter doesn't make the drive look like what the BIOS is expecting.  Perhaps the adapter does its effect after the BIOS would locate the drive, perhaps by using an "option ROM" (similar to a RAID controller).  In that case, the adapter might make the drive visible before the system runs any "boot code", so the drive could work before the operating system starts.  However, the BIOS wouldn't see it.

It's rather impossible to know exactly what's failing to work when we don't knowing more about that adapter, or perhaps about the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

The SATA card has to be bootable. If you are sure that it is generally you can change the BIOS boot order to allow it to boot from other devices.